# Как определить ботов социальных сетей?

Tags: php

Как определить ботов социальных сетей?

В данный момент система веб построена так, что для каждого зашедшего пользователя, на любой странице сайта, определяется его местоположение(страна). После чего данные заносятся в сессию и делается редирект. Таким образом, если клиент впервые посещает сайт, его редиректует.

Это стало проблемой для ботов социальных сетей, они не могут определить страницу, которой желаю поделиться.

Таким образом, я хочу определить известных ботов и для них не запускать механизм:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['COUNTRY']))){
// Detect country()
// Set to SESSION()
// Redirect()
}
```

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Какие есть идеи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

по userAgent?